# How to define /etc/apt/sources.list.d packages in Depends field in debian control file?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg, dependencies

My software depends on

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4052245BD4284CDD
echo "deb https://repo.iovisor.org/apt/$(lsb_release -cs) $(lsb_release -cs) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/iovisor.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bcc-tools libbcc-examples linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

How to specify these as dependencies in debian control file?